# Usuage of ? extends anyobject in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

```
    List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I have the above line of code. 
The object 'l' can refer any objects which can be Number any of its sub types.
I know that we can not add anyting to the above list.
Then what is the use of "? extends any_object" since we can not add anything to it ?
In what kind of context it is used ?
Can anyone please explain.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

It’s most useful for method arguments.  Consider this:

```
public void printFormatted(Collection<? extends Number> values) {

    NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

    for (Number value : values) {
        System.out.println(format.format(value));
    }

}
```

If I declare the method with `Collection<Number>`, callers *must* pass a Collection (or List or Set) whose generic type is known to be Number.  They *cannot* pass `Collection<Integer>`, because Collection<Integer> is not a subclass of Collection<Number> and in fact is not polymorphically compatible with Collection<Number>.

By declaring the method with `Collection<? extends Number>`, I am saying that callers can pass Collection<Number>, or Collection<Integer>, or Collection<Double>, etc.  List<Integer> or Set<Integer> is also acceptable, since the *class* is polymorphic, even though the generic type is not.

Comment: Thanks, This is much helpfull! :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of possible examples:

When you pass such method as argument, you can iterate over elements of such such list and use methods appropriate to `Number` class. You need to be aware that you cannot **add** any elements to such list. You are able to use `list.get()` method and that way, you're sure that you will get an **instanceof** `Number` class.

Such list is then called a *producer*. If you would need to **add** elements to list, instead of retrieving them, you would use `<? super Number>`. That rule is called PECS (*Producer Extends Consumer Super*).

Comment: This is a good example to understand. I much appreciate your time!!

Comment: @user3103957 Glad that  I could help you!